Is there a way for st_intersection to return a value of 0 instead of cutting non intersecting features?
I have a 1km buffer shapefile and a roads shapefile and I'm trying to figure out the total length of roads that intersect with each buffer so I can calculate road density within each buffer. There are a few buffers that do not intersect with any roads so they are cut from the result. I still need the values for those buffers even if they are equal to zero. Any insight would be appreciated thank you. My code is below:
### Loop to calculate each buffer and erase the original point, one point/buffer at a time
#START OF LOOP
for (i in 1:nrow(p_rep)){

  buff1km <- outerBuffer(p_rep[i,], dist)

 
  st_write(buff1km, "1kmbuff.shp", driver = "ESRI Shapefile", sep="", append = TRUE)
  
} #END OF LOOP

###  Read in the buffer shapefile
buffer_only <- st_read("1kmbuff.shp")

### read in roads shapefile: 
  ## Road shapefile accessed from state of michigan GIS opendata
  ## https://gis-michigan.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/Michigan::all-roads-v17a/about

roads <- read_sf(dsn = "All_Roads_(v17a).shp")
  # Distance (length) unit of measure is meters.
roads
roads.prep <- st_transform(roads, crs(buffer_only))

roads.buff  <- sf::st_intersection(roads.prep, buffer_only) %>%
  mutate(length_m = st_length(geometry))

I tried using st_intersection but it cut out the rows that didn't intersect.
Example data for roads and center points for buffers can be found at:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ll-VnNsGv29PHgAnZShNHU9QcvgX0v7F?usp=sharing

your code is not exactly reproducible, but I would suggest to calculate the intersection distance per some ID, and then left join it to the original data frame; dplyr::left_join() will add NA values for not joined rows. These can be converted to zero in a second step by leveraging dplyr::coalesce(our distance, 0)

I added a link to example data and some code. Sorry, I'm new to this.

You can join buffer_only to the resulting frame. If spatial st_join() is too expensive and you can identify your buffers by some unique id, you can use regular dplyr::right_join() or left_join, just make sure not to pass 2 sf objects:
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.12.1, GDAL 3.8.4, PROJ 9.3.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(dplyr)

st_intersection(roads, buffer_only) |> 
  mutate(length = st_length(geometry)) |> 
  right_join(st_drop_geometry(buffer_only)) |> 
  st_sf() |> 
  tidyr::replace_na(list(length = 0))
#> Warning: attribute variables are assumed to be spatially constant throughout
#> all geometries
#> Joining with `by = join_by(id_buff)`
#> Simple feature collection with 3 features and 3 fields (with 1 geometry empty)
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 1 ymin: 1 xmax: 3 ymax: 2
#> CRS:           NA
#>   id_road id_buff length              geometry
#> 1       1       2      2 LINESTRING (1 1, 3 1)
#> 2       2       2      1 LINESTRING (2 2, 2 1)
#> 3      NA       1      0      LINESTRING EMPTY


Example data:
buffer_only  <-
  st_as_sfc(c("POINT (1 4)", "POINT (2 1)")) |> 
  st_buffer(1) |> 
  st_sf(geometry = _, id_buff = 1:2)
buffer_only
#> Simple feature collection with 2 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 3 ymax: 5
#> CRS:           NA
#>   id_buff                       geometry
#> 1       1 POLYGON ((2 4, 1.99863 3.94...
#> 2       2 POLYGON ((3 1, 2.99863 0.94...

roads  <-
  st_as_sfc(c("LINESTRING (0 1, 4 1)", "LINESTRING (2 3, 2 1)")) |> 
  st_sf(geometry = _, id_road = 1:2)
roads  
#> Simple feature collection with 2 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 0 ymin: 1 xmax: 4 ymax: 3
#> CRS:           NA
#>   id_road              geometry
#> 1       1 LINESTRING (0 1, 4 1)
#> 2       2 LINESTRING (2 3, 2 1)

plot(buffer_only$geometry, col = "gold", axes = T)
plot(roads$geometry, lwd = 3, add = T)


Created on 2024-10-31 with reprex v2.1.1

Thank you for making an example dataset and for your solution. I have edited my question and included a link to example data if that helps. I tried this method and got the following error: Joining with by = join_by(SiteLink, Zone, Date, Year)
Error in vec_assign():
! Can't convert replace$length  to match type of data$length . I think the error has something to do with this part of the code: tidyr::replace_na(list(length = 0))

Good catch! In my example I didn't set a CRS so lengths are without units. Try replacing replace_na(list(length = 0)) with replace_na(list(length = units::set_units(0, m)))

Welcome to SO! The use of st_intersects() is generally more flexible, but you should also be able to use st_difference() and bind that to the results of st_intersection() which may be simpler when it comes to your use case. In this example we generate one line inside a polygon, another line that is partially inside a polygon, and one line that is entirely outside of the polygon. Most of the code below is setup.
I hope this helps!
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(mapview)

set.seed(1)

# outline
outline <- system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package = "sf") |>
    sf::st_read(quiet = TRUE) |>
    sf::st_transform(4326) |>
    sf::st_union() |>
    sf::st_as_sf()

# create a linestring within the polygon
line <- outline |>
    sf::st_sample(2) |>
    sf::st_combine() |>
    sf::st_cast("LINESTRING")

# a line partially inside
partial <- sf::st_as_sfc("LINESTRING(-79 34, -78 36)", crs = 4326)

# line outside
outside <- sf::st_as_sfc("LINESTRING(-80 34, -79.5 34)", crs = 4326)

# combine
lines <- c(line, partial, outside) |>
    sf::st_as_sf() |>
    dplyr::mutate(id = dplyr::row_number())

# rename geom
sf::st_geometry(lines) <- "geometry"

# get the intersection
int <- sf::st_intersection(lines, outline) |>
    dplyr::mutate(intersect = TRUE) |>
    dplyr::mutate(length = sf::st_length(geometry))

# get the difference and set length to 0
diff <- sf::st_difference(lines, outline) |>
    dplyr::mutate(intersect = FALSE) |>
    dplyr::mutate(length = units::as_units(0, "m"))

# bind together
res <- rbind(diff, int) |>
    dplyr::mutate(newid = dplyr::row_number())

# map results
mapview::mapview(outline) +
    mapview::mapview(res, zcol = "newid")


I would suggest to use sf::st_intersects() to count the number of features (roads) which intersects with buffers.
Let's prepare some data first (you will replace it with your shapefiles):
bb <- osmdata::getbb("Oborniki Śląskie", format_out = "sf_polygon") |>
  sf::st_centroid() |>
  sf::st_buffer(dist = 200) |>
  sf::st_bbox() #|>
  as.array()
#> Error in as.array.default(): argument "x" is missing, with no default
  osmdata::getbb()
#> Error in get_nominatim_query(place_name, featuretype, is_polygon, display_name_contains, : argument "place_name" is missing, with no default

h <- osmdata::opq(bb) |>
  osmdata::add_osm_feature(key = "highway") |>
  osmdata::osmdata_sf()

h <- h$osm_lines

buffer_only <- h[1:10, ] |>
  sf::st_buffer(dist = 8)

tmap::tmap_mode("plot")
#> tmap mode set to 'plot'
tmap::tm_shape(buffer_only) +
  tmap::tm_polygons() +
  tmap::tm_shape(h[30:45, ]) +
  tmap::tm_lines(lwd = 2)


We have 10 polygons (buffers) and 16 roads, and using st_intersects() we can check which (and how many of them) intersects with our polygons. st_intersects() creates a sparse geometry binary predicate list, like:
sf::st_intersects(buffer_only, h[30:45,])
#> Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 10, where the predicate
#> was `intersects'
#>  1: 5, 15
#>  2: (empty)
#>  3: 15, 16
#>  4: (empty)
#>  5: (empty)
#>  6: 15
#>  7: 15
#>  8: 10, 15
#>  9: 1
#>  10: (empty)

Where we can see that 1st buffer intersects with 2 ways, 2nd with 0, etc. Using sparse argument we can create FALSE/TRUE matrix which can be used to count number of intersected roads:
sf::st_intersects(buffer_only, h[30:45,], sparse = FALSE)
#>        [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
#>  [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#>  [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#>  [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[...]

Let's calculate number of intersecting roads for each buffer:
mat <- sf::st_intersects(buffer_only, h[30:45,], sparse = FALSE)

x <- unlist(lapply(1:10, function(i) length(which(mat[i, ] == TRUE))))

x
#>  [1] 2 0 2 0 0 1 1 2 1 0

The length you will calculate separately using st_length(), however you can use the result of as.data.frame(st_intersects()) to have number of buffer and number of intersecting road as separate rows in data frame, which might be useful.
Created on 2024-10-30 with reprex v2.1.0
